# How can I increase the number of concurrent connections to a streaming endpoint on a SpringBoot WebFlux app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty, project-reactor

I've created a barebones netty spring boot app in kotlin, imported just the Spring Reactive Web dependencies (`spring-boot-starter-webflux`, etc), and added a simple streaming endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("/stream")
    fun stream(): Flux<String> {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map { a: Long -> "returning $a" }
    }
```

The endpoint streams as expected for up to 9 client connections. But if I try to open a 10th connection there is no response. Similarly, if I try to call a simple hello world endpoint after opening 9 streaming connections there is no response. Closing one of the existing streaming connections allows the app to respond again.

Why is this happening, and how can I ensure that my app can stream to more than 9 clients at a time?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the application itself but in the fact I was opening the streams from chrome. Opening the streams via curl solved this problem.